# Issue with getters and setters Methods

Tags: c#, properties, casting, getter

In my `CustomView` class, `TaskText` and `ProjectText` are comboboxes. See the following property written for getting value from `TaskText`. My `TaskText` combobox contains list of Tasks. When I select specific task at runtime, it should store id of that Task which I've done in setters. But I don't understand, how do I get that id?

Later, I'll convert that id to integer and passed to method.

See the below code, which I've tried-

```
public Harvest_Task taskClass
{
    get
    {
        return new Harvest_Task { _id = Int32.Parse(TaskText.Text) }; // Here _id doesn't take the value.
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            TaskText.Text = (value._id).ToString();             
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? I don't understand your question.

Comment: In my getter, I'm not getting TaskText.Text in _id.

Comment: Just as a note are Getter/Setter properties should be light weight and not be able to throw exceptions.

MSDN Guidelines:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006.aspx

Comment: Why not? Step through it with your debugger.

Comment: Is your TaskText control private?

Comment: Yes. It was private. But, I tried by making them public. Now in getter, I'm getting System.FormatException.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you create a getter/setter to a specific property of a class and not the whole class itself...
Plus the way you're trying to do things, i recomment trying a Singleton class.